# How to use Google's User Timing feature in iOS analytics SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, analytics

I'm using Google Analytics in my iOS application and I'm trying to use their user timing feature, to record how responsive my backend HTTP server is. Code shown below:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [date timeIntervalSinceNow];
[self.tracker trackTimingWithCategory:@"request"
                            withValue:interval
                             withName:request.URL.absoluteString
                            withLabel:nil];
```

However, nothing is being shown in the reports in Google Analytics, any idea? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the issues you are encountering here is the negative value for second parameter. May be try something like this:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = -[date timeIntervalSinceNow];
[self.tracker trackTimingWithCategory:@"request"
                            withValue:interval
                             withName:request.URL.absoluteString
                            withLabel:nil];
```

Notice the extra "-" in the first line.

An alternative could be to use one of the other tracking mechanisms like events/custom variables or metrics.

Comment: I had the same symptoms but a different cause http://stackoverflow.com/a/20126034/1005983