# Google analytics timing not shown

Tags: ios, google-analytics, timing

I have implemented analytics for a iOS app, and everything is working fine, with the exception of timing. I can see the screens accessed, the events that took place, but I cannot see anywhere the timing info. I am sending successfully the information, the code is 200, but I don't find anywhere on the account the information that was sent. It should be visible in the App speed section? I don't have anything there. It's been 3 days since I have been using the analytics, but no info so far regarding the timing. Please help!

Comment: I had a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/20126034/1005983

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that even if google says that the parameters for sending the timing info (name and label) are optional, only after I filled out this stuff, the data started showing in my account.

Comment: Just come across your answer. Wow, good going Google. Do they know what "optional" means?

Answer (score 0):

With the SDK for Android V4 it is also essential to give value to the two variables called optional.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that logging a non-integer number causes trouble with getting the event logged as well.  Make sure that when you convert your time interval to milliseconds, the result is an integer value.